# Solve for $n$ in $2^Mn=1.00001^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $2^Mn=1.00001^n$, how to compute $n$ in respect of $M$? Assume $M$ is a constant.

I don't know how to represent $n$ by $M$. Any suggestions? Might need to apply logarithms or root somehow.

Comment: What if I told you that this can't be solved with just logs and roots?

Comment: Essentially, $2^M=\dfrac 1n$ In which case $M \approx -\dfrac{\log n}{\log 2}$. You will need to provide information about what values of $M$ or $n$ you are interested in.

Comment: M is a positive constant. We can assume we know what M is.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is of the form $kx=a^x$ with $k,a$ constant. This cannot be solved for $x$ with logarithms or roots alone. Rather, a very powerful special function – the [Lambert W (product logarithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1) – is needed, defined as follows:
$$x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$$
Many equations involving linear and exponential terms can be solved this way, and the Wikipedia page I linked conveniently has an example of how to solve $kx=a^x$:
$$kx=a^x=e^{x\ln a}$$
$$kxe^{-x\ln a}=1$$
$$-x\ln a\cdot e^{-x\ln a}=-\frac{\ln a}k$$
$$-x\ln a=W\left(-\frac{\ln a}k\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln a}k\right)}{\ln a}$$
Substituting $n=x$, $a=1.00001$ and $k=2^M$ leads to the solution for the given equation:
$$n=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln1.00001}{2^M}\right)}{\ln1.00001}$$
The top branch of the Lambert W yields a solution approximately equivalent to $2^{-M}$ for $M\gtrsim-5$. The bottom branch, as mentioned in the comments of *this* answer, skyrockets for small values of $M$.

Comment: So is W a function? Or what is W?

Comment: @Nick It is a function. I've linked the Wikipedia page for it.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks. Is there further simplification steps we can make? I have learned Lambert W before, not sure if there is a less complex way to solve the question.

Comment: @Nick I've already mentioned the approximation given in the comments. Other than that, there isn't a less complex way; in general any equating of a linear and an exponential term is going to need the Lambert W.

Comment: There are two branches of W and so there are two solutions to this equation.   The smaller one seems to have close to the series $1/k + 1/(100k)^2 +1/(100k)^4 + \cdots,$ where $k=2^M$.  The other is is over $10^6$ if $M=1$ or $2$.